# Launch a class library interface in console app vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2019, desktop-application, class-library

Good morning,
I am new to VB.NET.
I have created an interface in which I can write data and transfer it to a database with a submit button, I used class library template in visual studio 2019. This template generates a .dll file after compilation.
I would like to create a .exe file. So, I created a new console project to the solution and I set it to
the starter project. But, I did not know how to launch the interface created from a console application.
Is there a method in VB.NET that launch an interface of a class library? Or am I doing things wrong.
I will need the .exe for the final user.

Comment: If your application is actually WinForms then create a WinForms application project. Just disable the Application Framework and write your own `Main` method to display whatever form you want at startup.

Comment: The application type is a class library and not a windows form application

Comment: You said that you created a Console application to display WinForms forms. That's wrong. If you want to display WinForms forms then your application is a not a Console application so don't create a Console application project. Create a WinForms application project if you want to display WinForms forms. The fact that those forms are defined in a separate library is neither here nor there.

Comment: Labels and textbox are lanuched automatically when running the class library. 
How to specify that in the main function. Is the there a method to launch all the graphic components created?

Comment: @Arij Bt. It seems that jmcilhinney confused "interface" with "graphical user interface". Could you rephrase your question so it better expresses what you are doing: you have exposed some Interface from a class library and you want to use it in a separate console application. (which is usually done by putting a reference from the console application to the class library)

Comment: @BartJolling Well I changed the whole project to a winform.

Comment: Still, you should clarify in your question what you mean by "interface" since I thought your description matched this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/interfaces/. This will help future readers of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a C# WinForms Application project targeting .NET Framework, VS generates the following class to provide the entry point:

```cs
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

When you create a similar project in VB, the VB Application Framework is enabled by default. That framework hides the entry point from and you just specify the form type you want to be the first displayed. If you disable the Application Framework then you lose some automatic functionality, e.g. splash screen and shutdown on last form close, but you also can/must provide your own `Main` method. The VB equivalent to that C# code would be this:

```vb
Module Program

    <STAThread>
    Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
        Application.Run(New Form1)
    End Sub

End Module
```

You can do that in your own VB WinForms Application project and then replace `Form1` with whatever form you want, including a form defined in a separate referenced assembly. You'll need to specify that module or the `Main` method as the Startup Object in the project properties.